# Getting full xml of a node, while iterating through a boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I have a problem getting full xml text of boost::property_tree while iterating using BOOST_FOREACH.

Xml file is something like this:

```
<foo>
    <bar param1="val1" param2="val2">
        <one>some text</one>
        <two>some text</two>
    </bar>
    <bar param1="val3" param2="val4">
        <one>some text</one>
        <two>some text</two>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

The code I use to iterate through is next:

```
ptree pt;
read_xml(input_stream, pt);
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type const& bar, pt.get_child("foo")) 
{
     std::ostringstream oss;
     write_xml(oss, bar.second);
     std::cout << oss.str();
}
```

As output I receive (for each `<bar>`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<one>some text</one>
<two>some text</two>
```

Question is, how can i receive full xml text of the `<bar>` tag, using above loop?
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bar param1="val1" param2="val2">
    <one>some text</one>
    <two>some text</two>
</bar>
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT :** added ready to copy & past piece of code

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

const std::string xml_str =
        "<foo>"
            "<bar param1=\"val1\" param2=\"val2\">"
                "<one>some text</one>"
                "<two>some text</two>"
            "</bar>"
            "<bar param1=\"val3\" param2=\"val4\">"
                "<one>more text</one>"
                "<two>more text</two>"
            "</bar>"
        "</foo>";

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::property_tree;
    using namespace boost::property_tree::xml_parser;

    std::istringstream iss(xml_str);
    ptree pt;
    read_xml(iss, pt);

    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type const& bar, pt.get_child("foo")) 
    {
         std::ostringstream oss;
         write_xml(oss, bar.second);
         std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I'd say this is not possible without simply serializing the subtree to a stream. If you make the code a SSCCE, I could have done it for you. Right now, that would take to much time (5 minutes to get the sample going is more than the time required to show a proof of concept).

Comment: @sehe, I've added code that could be simply copied & pasted

Comment: @Apokal [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d4ae2e5a0ddd777) seems to work, but I very much doubt that it is the best way to do it. Hope it helps until you get a real answer.

Comment: @cv_and_he that's exactly what I'd do, since ptree's are not an xml library. Otherwise, I'd switch to libxml2 or pugixml (<- rather neat, can be done header only)

Comment: cv_and_he, sehe thanks a lot, your solution is really simple! So, someone please, post an answer so I can accept it, because I don't think there will be an answer soon.